# Find out if a process running as root exists

Tags: python, linux, process, subprocess

I have a program that needs to know if a certain process (also part of the program, but running as a daemon) owned by root exists. The process is started from within the program using `pkexec` so that the program itself can run as a normal user.

Normally, if I need to know if a process is running, I would use `os.kill(pid, 0)` and catch the resulting exception. Unfortunately, in this case, Python simply spits an `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`, regardless of whether the process exists or not.

Apart from manually parsing the output of `ps aux | grep myprogram`, is there a simple way of knowing if the process exists *without resorting to an external library like psutils*? psutils seems like an awfully large dependency to add for such a simple task.

Comment: a normal user-level process couldn't `kill` a root-owned process anyways. That's not python causing the error, it's the underlying OS properly forbidding the operation. You can try rummaging around in `/proc/<pid>` and finding your process by looking at what each proc entry's `exe` symlink is pointing at.

Comment: `os.kill(pid, 0)` doesn't kill the process, it simply sends it an empty signal. The function is unfortunately named. It only kills the process when the second parameter is an appropriate signal from the `signal` module.

Comment: As a follow on to @MarcB, you can scan /proc/<pid>/status files that include the program name, uid and gid.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: doesn't matter. a user-level process canot send a signal to a root-level process. You can trivially try it from a shell, e.g. `kill -0 1` will try to send sig0 to `init`, and fail with "operation not permitted".

Comment: Thanks to your hints, I solved it by just using `if os.path.exists('/proc/'+str(pid))`. I already had the pid since I was running the process via `subprocess.Popen()`. If either of you wants to post this as an answer, I'll accept it, as I hadn't thought of looking in `/proc`

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi - you run the risk that the pid has been recycled. Peeking at cmdline or status may still be a good idea.

Comment: The process runs for all of about 10 seconds so practically speaking, there's no danger of that. But thanks, I'll add the check just to be on the safe side.

Comment: if you ran it with subprocess.Popen(), can't you poll() it to see if it's still running?

Comment: Sadly, no. `pkexec` appears to do something wonky and `poll()` is unable to account for it.

Comment: In the end, I abandoned this line of attack and solved the problem a different way.

Answer (score 1):

[os.geteuid()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.geteuid)

*"Return the current process’s effective user id."*

root's effective uid is zero:

```
if os.geteuid() == 0:
    print('running as root')
else:
    print('no root for you')
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, sorry. As I said, I'm launching a root process from a non-root process and I want to know if the root process still exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the pid you can use [`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/):

```
if psutil.Process(the_pid).is_running():
    print('Process is running')
else:
    print('Process is *not* running')
```

Bonus points: this works with python from 2.4 to 3.3 and with linux, OS X, Windows, FreeBSD, Sun Solaris and probably more.

Checking whether `/proc/the-pid` exists only works on *nix machines, not on windows.

Note also that simply checking `/proc/the-pid` is **not** enough to conclude that the process is running. The OS is free to reuse the pids, hence if the process ended and a different process was spawned with the same pid you are screwed.

You must also save somewhere the creation time of the original process. Then to check if the process exist you should first check `/proc/the-pid` and then check that the creation time of that process matches what you saved. `psutil` does this automatically.